# DotNet Build - Is it possible to import the error list into Visual Studio or another editor?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core

I'm going through and updating several projects from .Net 4.6 to .Net Core.  I'm running the new  "DotNet Build" which runs from the command line.  As I convert to .Net Core, I get back several hundred error rows like this:

> C:\myPath\MyFile.cs(141,3): error CS1061: 'Type' does not contain a definition for 'IsGenericType'
>
> C:\myPath\MyFile2.cs(261,3): error CS1061: 'Type' does not contain a definition for 'IsGenericType'

Rather than manually looking up each file and line in the project, is there a way to navigate the error file much like the traditional Visual Studio build's error list or NotePad++'s find in files?

EDIT: Thanks for the ideas.  What I've found is that if I create a project from scratch I get the desired behavior - my code is validated against the .Net Core language.  Clearly there is a problem with the project I am porting to Core.  I'll look into the project file and project.json and report back if I find something worth sharing.

Comment: If you open the ErrorList window, you can navigate to the error by double clicking on each error.

Comment: You are jockying the command line.  Use  the `>` operator to redirect output to a file.

Comment: Why don't you just open the project in VS, instead of using the command line?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to initiate a .Net Core build from within Visual Studio.  I think it just builds against .Net 4.5/4.6.  Building from VS would probably solve the problem.

Comment: dotnet core projects from within Visual Studio call out to the `dotnet.exe` tooling.  You may need to ensure that you have the tools installed? See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=824849